# Kendo-ui-angular controls in .NET 4.5 application

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I have setup my angular2 application on .NET 4.5 and included all the libraries that are required for angular2 in my application. The initial app component is running fine. Now I have included all the required @progress/kendo-angular -* libs in my package.json and restored the packages. I just added one pie chart in my app module. when I run this application I am getting the errors in console stating unable to get the kendo libraries. Like

> GET failed for http://localhost:59086/@progress/kendo-angular-buttons

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.20.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, ButtonsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I have updated the question with all the code where I have referred the new kendo controls.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to be sure you can get the private NPM Packages?

`npm view @progress/kendo-angular-grid versions`

From http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/

Also, did you `npm install` all the packages? e.g. `npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-buttons @progress/kendo-angular-l10n @angular/animations`? When you do this, you may also see dependencies in the console. The above statement from the above link wasn't adequate, from what I recall. I ended up having to install most of the Kendo packages, including internationalization.

Note above this is install `@angular/animations`.

Comment: On the bit about animations, I believe you need to ensure you have
`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';` in your app.module.ts along with adding `BrowserAnimationsModule` to the imports section in the same file.